# Styling Hubspot Forms with css - Oceanwp theme - Elementor pro

Tags: wordpress

Hope I'm in the right place.  Been sent here from the hubspot forums for different help.  I've got this site with hubspot forms, but they only display at a 1/3 column. I've placed both of the following codes into the style sheet of Oceanwp theme (havent needed a child theme yet, trying to avoid that, I only placed it here temporarily to see if it works before creating the child theme if needed).  I also placed it in the css injectors in elementor in the element itself, and in hidden elements on the page in various places (trying to figure out when the columns get set as the page loads and trying to get in front of it).  I'm not really great with css or html, but i do have rudimentary understanding of how they work, I just cant write it.

Heres one of my forms, and the two pieces of code I have tried.  Please help!!

http://staging.safetybathtubs.com/contact/

```
.hbspt-form .hs-form fieldset {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hs-form fieldset {
max-width: none!important;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to make the form take up the space of the iframe?  Also, it's generally a good idea to have a child theme for Wordpress.  It allows you to override your current themes functions and CSS without losing your changes when there are updates.

Comment: I think I am trying to get the iframe to go full width?  I want the whole form to be as wide as the column I put it in.  I hear you on the child theme, I've just been trying to do everything outside of actually getting into that code, because I know so little.  Surely there must be a way to solve this without creating a child theme for these few lines of code?  Thanks for your reply!